Qdrant filter for nodes when running vector_store.query()
The filtering use cases I've seen use client.search() but the following uses vector_store.query() to fetch query results, and getting nodes with their scores after. How do I integrate a parameter to apply filters to node.metadata?
class VectorDBRetriever(BaseRetriever):
    """Retriever over a qdrant vector store."""
    def __init__(
    self,
    vector_store: QdrantVectorStore,
    embed_model: Any,
    query_mode: str = "hybrid",
    similarity_top_k: int = 2,
    ) -> None:
        self._vector_store = vector_store
        self._embed_model = embed_model
        self._query_mode = query_mode
        self._similarity_top_k = similarity_top_k
        super().__init__()
    def _retrieve(self, query_bundle: QueryBundle) -> List[NodeWithScore]:
        index = VectorStoreIndex.from_vector_store(
        vector_store=vector_store, service_context=service_context)


        """Retrieve."""
        query_embedding = embed_model.get_query_embedding(
        query_bundle.query_str
        )
        vector_store_query = VectorStoreQuery(
        query_embedding=query_embedding,
        similarity_top_k=self._similarity_top_k,
        mode=self._query_mode,
        )

        query_result = vector_store.query(vector_store_query)
        
        nodes_with_scores = []
        processor = SimilarityPostprocessor(similarity_cutoff=0.75)
        
        for index, node in enumerate(query_result.nodes):
            print(node.metadata )


            score: Optional[float] = None
            if query_result.similarities is not None:
                score = query_result.similarities[index]
                nodes_with_scores.append(NodeWithScore(node=node, score=score))
        return nodes_with_scores
retriever = VectorDBRetriever(
vector_store, embed_model, query_mode="hybrid", similarity_top_k=10
)
query_engine = RetrieverQueryEngine.from_args(
 retriever, service_context=service_context
)



You can pass Qdrant filters to the QdrantVectorStore#query() method using the qdrant_filters kwarg. It will take priority over any conditions inside of  the VectorStoreQuery object itself.
